# (Fancyhdr) How to center text, but aligned to the left?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, fancyhdr, text

I'm trying to make a header for my thesis document. It requires the text to be left aligned, but centered, like this:

[image]

I have tried doing it with this aproach:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
%other packages
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
% ------- PORTADA ------- 

\title{PORTADA}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}    
\fancyhead[L]{\centering{Some text

some really long long long long text

other long looong text}}
\fancyhead[R]{Some text

}
\fancyheadoffset[lh]{2cm}
```

And the result is this:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. What is your `\documenclass` to add in your question?

Comment: oh, sorry I forget about it, it's a report. I will edit the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the material in a centered cell of a tabular (and remove the space between columns with `@{}` so the text is immediately at the left margin).

I have added the **showframe** package for better visualisation of the layout.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
%other packages
\usepackage{showframe} % to show the frames of the page

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}    
\fancyhead[L]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c} 
Some text \\
some really long long long long text\\ 
other long looong text
\end{tabular}}

\fancyhead[R]{Some text}

% dimensions suggested by the fancyhdr package when theses two lines are commented
\setlength{\headheight}{43.5pt} 
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2pt}

\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

% ------- PORTADA ------- 

\title{PORTADA}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @quark67, using that configuration with tabular solved the problem!